# How to subtract items from one list to another usinp zip funcitons in python

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, absolute-value, python-zip

guys I have the following code:

```
def disFn(a, b):
    return[[abs(m-n) for o,p in zip(m,n)] for m,n in zip(a[1],b[1])]
```

But it is not working.. What I need to be done is for ech tuple in the list down bellow return the difference between each of its values in the tuples, for instance... I want to get the following tuple

```
( abs(0.0  - 8.708170812), abs(8.708170812 - 0.0), abs(4.088197921 - 10.518235207), abs(11.366319879999999 - 7.668395996), abs(12.638763287 - 10.522399903), abs(11.078233943 - 7.302185059), abs(10.025102839 - 6.417022705), abs(8.415467337 - 6.146172005), abs(8.194840093 - 10.448354985), abs(13.455056175000001 -5.149291993)),


data = [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]),
    ('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993]),
    ('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]),
    ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]),
    ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]),
    ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]),
    ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),
    ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),
    ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),
    ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def disFn(a, b):
    return[abs(m-n) for m,n in zip(a[1],b[1])]


print(disFn(data[0], data[1]))
```

Output:

```
[8.708170812, 8.708170812, 6.430037286, 3.697923883999999, 2.1163633839999996, 3.7760488840000006, 3.6080801340000006, 2.2692953320000004, 2.253514892, 8.305764182]
```

Why nested list comprehension, only one layer list comprehension works fine.

Maybe I do not get your point?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you don't need to use zip() at all.  This should give you the result you're asking for:

```
tuple([abs(values[0] - values[1]) for key, values in data])
```